# how to count the number Appear most times from each row for pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,1,5],
                   [2,3,4,4,6],
                   [7,2,2,2,5],
                   [21,3,4,3,6]], index=[1,2,3,4], columns=list('ABCDE'))
```

The resulting value of df

```
    A   B   C   D   E
1   1   2   3   1   5
2   2   3   4   4   6
3   7   2   2   2   5
4   21  3   4   3   6
```

How can i know which number has the most occurrences in each row?

For example:

```
row 1: 1    appears two times
row 2: 4    appears two times
row 3: 2    appears three times
```

and so on....

Comment: Formatted DataFrame declaration to make the rows easier to see.  Fixed language.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) to get value and count of appearing then [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) to join them:

```
value = df.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0], axis=1)
count = df.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().iloc[0], axis=1)

out = pd.concat([value, count], axis=1).reset_index()

out.columns = ['row_num', 'val', 'appearing']
out['row_num'] = 'row ' + out['row_num'].astype(str) + ':'
out['appearing'] = 'appears ' + out['appearing'].astype(str) + ' times'

In [64]: out
Out[64]:
  row_num  val        appearing
0  row 1:    1  appears 2 times
1  row 2:    4  appears 2 times
2  row 3:    2  appears 3 times
3  row 4:    3  appears 2 times
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for idx, i in df.iterrows():
    l = list(i)
    list_of_counts = [l.count(x) for x in l]
    m = max(list_of_counts)
    print ("row " + str(idx) + ":" + str(l[list_of_counts.index(m)]) +" appears " + str(m) +" times")
```

row 1:1 appears 2 times

row 2:4 appears 2 times

row 3:2 appears 3 times

row 4:3 appears 2 times